# Airflow plugin - add button to the DAG page

Tags: airflow

I developed new Airflow plugin that let's you edit the source of your dag files:
https://github.com/ohadmata/simple-dag-editor

The plugin is installed in a new scope (View).
To enable a better integration I want to add new button to the default DAG view that redirect to my plugin and open the editor on the selected dag file.
It is possible to do that using the airflow plugin interface?

I am talking about this line of buttons:
[image]

As I said, I want to add a button with url like this: http://airflow/dag_editor?id=dag_id
Thanks!